# Should I distribute my application in the App Store or is there another, more appropriate way?

Tags: ios, app-store

My company provides a solution that links companies to users. We already have the user application available in the App Store with around 100.000 downloads.

Currently, we only have a web platform for the company part of our solution, but we are developing another mobile application too, dedicated to these companies. However, since we plan to have at most a few hundreds of downloads, I was wondering if the App Store was the most efficient way to share this application, or if there was another way that I wouldn't know?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a video from WWDC 2019 called [App Distribution – From Ad-hoc to Enterprise](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/304/), which explains in detail all our distribution options via App Store:

> Whether you want to share your app with a few colleagues, deliver it
>   to employees within an organization, or release it to the world,
>   there's a distribution mechanism designed to fit your needs.
>   Familiarize yourself with each app deployment model, learn how to
>   choose the one that's best for you, and learn about essential testing
>   and distribution tools.

---

Based on what you wrote, I would say you could use the "**In-House**" or "**Custom Apps**" models.

[image: distribution]

> Should I distribute my application in the App Store?

Yes, I'd say so.

Comment: Thank you for the link. It makes sense.